# Created filtered index is not used in execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I am trying to make use of filtered index on sql server 2008 R2.

I am able to create the index successfully but while executing the query the created index is not used, even after dropping all the indexes using primary key.

I have also tried to clear the plan cache but no change in execution plan.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_test] ON [MyTable]
(
    COL01 ASC
)
WHERE ([FK_ID]=(34))

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductID INT 
SET @ProductID = 34 
SET @SQL = N'select top 1 COL01 from [MyTable] 
where [FK_ID] =' + CAST(@ProductID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL    

select top 1 COL01 from [MyTable] 
where [FK_ID] = cast( 34 as varchar(10))
```

I have checked similar questions but could not find any solution for it. When tried similar script with adventureworks 2012 data base the created index was used there.

So, is there any setting needed to be done at database level or how to make use of the filtered index?